# How to put variable value inside another variable name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a javascript variable

```
var varNameValue = "Name";
```

Now i want to create another variable using the value of `varNameValue` inside the name of the Other

```
var x(varNameValue)y = "abc";
```

So that my new variable name becomes

```
var xNamey = "abc";
```

Is there any way to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly in JavaScript. If you know the content in which it is run, then you can. For example, if this is in a browser, and it is in the global context (which maps to `window`), then you could do

```
window["x"+varNameValue+"y"] = "abc";
```

Similarly if it is on an object

```
var obj = {};
obj["x"+varNameValue+"y"] = "abc";
```

But just as a standalone var without any context? Nah.

Comment: this edit is so much better than the former answer.

Comment: also, this["x"+varNameValue+"y"] = "abc"; can be used.

Comment: Definitely... if `this` is correct, which is always a challenge. The bigger question is, why would you want to set the name of a `var` variably? In an object, yes, I get it; but just out there?

Answer (score 1):

```
var varNameValue = "Name";
eval("var x" + varNameValue + "y = 'abc';")
alert(xNamey);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

var obj={}

var nameValue="Name";

obj["x"+ nameValue +"y"]= "abc"

Then you can access it using obj.xNamey